# Best way to create list [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6] ] in Python

Tags: python, list

I want to generate the list of list `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`

I have attached some python codes but I do not know what to pick among them in terms of efficiency:

```
[[y + x for x in range(3)] for y in [1,4]]
[[y for y in range(z, z + 3)] for z in [1,4]]
[[y, y + 1, y + 2] for y in [1,4]]
```

They all generate the required list however I do not feel satisfied with how they are written (since they are all dependent on getting values from the list [1,4]) and considering that I am only a beginner in the Python language. Can you also recommend me a good way to generate the list required? Thank you

Comment: @python_user they all use "for var in [1,4]". I would want to replace them with non-dependent code that uses range(), etc instead of depending on a preset list [1,4].

Comment: It likely depends on the real world situation what the answer here needs to be. Clearly, in an example as trivial as yours, simply the literal `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` is best, but you appear to want to generate this based on some parameters. How can these parameters vary? Does the number of columns vary? The numer of rows? The initial offset? What ranges would be possible or typical? Is a "good way" a fast one? A readable one? One that allows you to only compute the part of the data that will be used?

Comment: @Grismar I would like a code that would only depend on atmost 1 hyperparameter that I would preset instead of the list [1,4]. I am thinking of using range functions with atmost 1 of them preset with a single hyperparameter

Comment: For 1 parameter based upon the length of list you could have: `[list(range(i, i+3)) for i in range(1, L+1, 3)]`.  For posted example, L = 6.  If parameter is based upon size of sublist you could have: `[list(range(i, i+n)) for i in range(1, 6+1, n)]`, where in posted example,  n = 3.

Comment: @DarrylG that is much simpler solution for my problem, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[y + x for x in range(3)] for y in [1,4]]
```

In this code, Giving the value 4 is not the best way because in order to print a list like this

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18], [19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27], [28, 29, 30]]
```

you might have to write

```
[[y + x for x in range(3)] for y in [1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22,25,28]]
```

which is not an easy and generalised code.Instead you can write

```
[[ x for x in range(y,y+3)] for y in range(1,6,3)]
```

or

```
[[ x for x in range(y,y+3)] for y in range(1,n,3)]
```

Comment: Note that, if you'd be using large numbers of values, using a third party package like `numpy` might greatly speed things up and you could use something like `np.array(range(n*m)).reshape(n, m)` (or provide `-1` instead of the latter `m`)